# Laravel 5 Database Connection with PHP MyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, laravel-5

I have got Laravel 5 set up on a shared hosting package (not locally) and I have a database. I have database credentials THESE ARE NOT ACTUAL CREDENTIALS BUT THIS IS THE FORMAT:

**server**: sharreddb........
**database/username**: [DATABASE NAME]
**password**: aaaaaa

In laravel 5, in the .env file, it asks for:
DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD

Which of the above credential information will go into each section in the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Yo could try:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_phpmyadmin_db_name
DB_USERNAME=your_phpmyadmin_username
DB_PASSWORD=your_phpmyadmin_password
```

You must check that the phpmyadmin credentials are working.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.